# Can you create a phase change line in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Does highcharts support phase change lines ? It may be called multiple things but im looking to see if an X axis delineation line can be drawn in highcharts. It is used to specify a specific date in time where something in the environment changed. The chart reader would then look at that line and see if that change to the environment impacted the data represented by the lines in the line chart.

Anyone know if this can be done with high charts ? Sample image attached.

[image: pc line example]

Comment: So like a plot line? [Highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines)

Comment: Thank you! Yes that is exactly what I was looking for but was using a different term for it hence I could not find it in the documentation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great answer from Ondkloss: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines That page shows exactly what I was looking for.